# Align buttons to bottom of card using bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using the following code to generate a card for some items. The button on the bottom of the card needs to be aligned to the bottom of the card, for doing this I am using the following:

```
return '
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card detailpage-related-items" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column p-4 card-detailpage" style="width: 100%;"><img class="d-flex recommended-products-thumbnail" src="https://iproject1.ip.aimsites.nl/pics/' . $afbeelding . '">
                    <h4 class="card-title">' . $voorwerpnaam . '</h4>
                    <h5 class="card-title"><strong>€' . $prijs . '</strong></h5>
                    <p>Loopt tot: ' . $eindtijd . '</p>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <form action="/detail.php" method="get">
                            <input type="hidden" name="veiling" id="veiling" value="' . $voorwerpnummer . '">
                            <input type="submit" class="bid-button mt-auto" value="Bieden">
                        </form> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
```

`d-flex` and `flex-column` on the `card-body`,
`mt-auto` on the button and
`text-center` in an enclosing `<div>` around the form for the buttons.

However the output is as below:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 divs with buttons by combining images and titles within the card body into a single div. Then add the h-100 and justify-content-between classes to the div containing the card-body class. I think this will solve your problem.

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="card detailpage-related-items" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="card-body d-flex h-100 justify-content-between flex-column p-4 card-detailpage" style="width: 100%;"><img class="d-flex recommended-products-thumbnail" src="https://iproject1.ip.aimsites.nl/pics/' . $afbeelding . '">
      <div>
        <h4 class="card-title">' . $voorwerpnaam . '</h4>
        <h5 class="card-title"><strong>€' . $prijs . '</strong></h5>
        <p>Loopt tot: ' . $eindtijd . '</p>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center">
        <form action="/detail.php" method="get">
          <input type="hidden" name="veiling" id="veiling" value="' . $voorwerpnummer . '">
          <input type="submit" class="bid-button mt-auto" value="Bieden">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```